# Can I activate Nim Deathmantle's creature saving ability more than once in a turn?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

My opponent attacks with two 4/4 creatures. I block each of them with one 2/2 creature, but have [Nim Deathmantle](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=209289) on the field, currently not equipped to anything. When my two 2/2 creatures are put into the graveyard after the damage step, can I pay 4 mana to save one of them, equipping the Nim Deathmantle to it, and then pay another 4 to save the other, unequip from the first 2/2 creature, and now have it equipped to the other?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes.

It's a triggered ability, so it'll trigger every time a creature dies. If multiple creatures die simultaneously, you choose how to stack the triggers, then get to resolve them one by one.

From [the card's Oracle rulings](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=209289):

> 1/1/2011  If multiple nontoken creatures are put into your graveyard
>   from the battlefield at the same time, Nim Deathmantle's second
>   ability triggers that many times. You put the triggered abilities on
>   the stack in any order, so you'll determine in which order they
>   resolve. If you pay {4} more than once, each card you paid {4} for
>   will end up on the battlefield under your control, and Nim Deathmantle
>   will end up attached to the last card that returned to the battlefield
>   this way that it could equip.